# HP DL360 G5 will not boot with all DIMM slots full

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

If I install memory into every DIMM slot the server will not boot, no display will be shown via VGA. ILO 2 detects these slots' memory as being "Not installed". If I remove the memory from the two slots it will boot.

These slots are 6D and 8D.

What should I do?

It's 8 x 2GB DIMMs. All the same type.

Comment: You removed 2 DIMMs and it booted. Can you use those 2 DIMMs (by removing two others) and seeing if it still boots? It could be a bad DIMM

Comment: @mfinni still boots which ever DIMMs are in, it's not a faulty DIMM, checked them all.

Comment: Could be a bad slot on the board, too. Can you use those slots in a valid non-full config?

Comment: @mfinni yeah that's the weird thing they work and the BIOS recognises the memory in those slots.

Comment: Latest BIOS installed?

Comment: Which specific part are they; 397411-B21 or 461826-B21?

Comment: @mfinni it's aftermarket RAM, the thing is it boots fine with one RAM stick in 6D or 8D and then says there's a bad memory configuration in bank D (expected because there should be two DIMMs not one) but when I put both DIMMs in it just does a long beep and doesn't boot (no BIOS/VGA output).

Comment: How many ranks are used per DIMM? (I presume 2, but it would be nice to confirm that it is not 4).

Comment: @Hennes how can I tell?

Comment: I am not good at explaining it, so I will just point at this link: http://serverfault.com/questions/69612/dimms-single-vs-double-vs-quad-rank

Comment: I am having the exact same problem with ML110 G6. System worked with same 4 Kingston (4GB each) for about 6 years, on 24/7 (2500 some days on). All of a sudden 2 of the slots stopped working with same RAM modules :( running ESXi 6.5

Answer (score 1):

Does the server have both CPU's installed? Is the ram RDIMM or UDIMM? Had a DL380 G6 that had the same behaviour. We exceed the supported UDIMM's for a single processor, so that could be the same thing. HP Support missed it too and swapped the mainboard before we realized what it was.

I know this is an old question, but it may be relevant to people searching.

Answer (score 0):

You should call HP Support and open a ticket.

If you don't have support, you should try these DIMMs in other slots.

Comment: DIMMs work in other slots, the DIMMs are fine and so are the slots.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts would be:

a) Working with pairs of DIMMs, boot the server with a SmartStart CD and run the memory diagnostics.  Repeat for each pair.

b) Boot the server from the terminal release firmware CD for the G5 and update the BIOS, Etc. (just in case)

c) Like others have said, go down the hardware fault route.

Comment: The DIMMs work fine in every slot, Updated all the firmware. Not sure what else to do, the slots work.